# CoreData and SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, save, swiftui

hello i'm try to implement Core Data and swiftUI for my project.

I created an Entity called Aeroporti, which contain 2 attributes iataAPT : String and icaoAPT: string.

I want to save simple data on that.

I setup the app delegate like this:

```
  // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "testFirebaseCoreData")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

my content view list the field icaoAPT in the entity Aeroporti

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm : DataManager
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Aeroporti.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Aeroporti.icaoAPT, ascending: true)]) var aeroport : FetchedResults<Aeroporti> // crea la variabile che contiene le ricette
   
    var body: some View {
        List{
            HStack{
                
               // NOT WORKING IF USING DataMANAGER
//                Button(action: {
//                    self.dm.provaSalva()
//                }) {
//                    Text("save from manager")
//                }
                
                saveFromView    // button save from view
            }
            ForEach(aeroport, id: \.self) { apt in
                Text(apt.icaoAPT ?? "sconosciuto")
//                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    var saveFromView : some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            let apt = Aeroporti(context: self.managedObjectContext)
            apt.iataAPT = "MFM"
            apt.icaoAPT = "VMMC"
            
            do {
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                print("airport saved.")
                
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }) {
            
            Text("save fromview")
        }
        
    }
}
```

all working fine and the data is saved if I use the button (saveFromView) in the ContentView.

now, in order to better handle the data I have create a DataManager where I put the same code to save the data in the entity, and I try to lunch this code on the content view via a button (save from manager) but it doest work, i'm getting the error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)" when it save.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


class DataManager:  ObservableObject {
    
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    
    func provaSalva() {
        let apt = Aeroporti(context: managedObjectContext)
        apt.iataAPT = "MFM"
        apt.icaoAPT = "VMMC"
        
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            print("airport saved.")
            
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

the question is?? why.. is the same code... how can I solve this issue if I want to handle the save data not in the ContentView.

thanks for the help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try. This is the implementation I use for my app.

```
class DataManager {
    //MARK: - Setup
        
    //Singleton object
    static let defaults = DataManager()
    private init() {}
    
    //Managed object context
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    //Save context, if changes were made
    func save() {
        if moc.hasChanges {
            do {
                print("Sucess!!")
                try moc.save()
            } catch {
                print("Error while saving managedObjectContext \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Insert

    //What you want to save
    func provaSalva() {
        let apt = Aeroporti(context: moc)
        apt.iataAPT = "MFM"
        apt.icaoAPT = "VMMC"
        
        save()
    }
}
```

Your `saveFromView`:

```
var saveFromView : some View {
    Button(action: {
        DataManager.defaults.provaSalva()
    }) {
        Text("save fromview")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

solved by passing the db to the function

```
 func provaSalva(dbCore: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let apt = Aeroporti(context: dbCore)
        apt.iataAPT = "MFM"
        apt.icaoAPT = "VMMC"
        
        do {
            try dbCore.save()
            print("airport saved.")
            
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, although I don’t really understand why it does and why it is necessary. Why can’t we just create the moc inside the DataManager?